# Datatables server side rendering with Django taking long time to respond

Tags: django, datatables

Good day guys.

I am using datatables with almost 2000 rows.
My problem is, it is taking 7-9 seconds to load the page.

I tried to implement server side rendering using django_datatables_view: https://pypi.org/project/django-datatables-view/.

It seems working because i am receiving the right response with its data but still it was taking 7-9 seconds to load the page. I am missing something?
See screenshots below:

[image: Data response[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x8wW.jpg)

[image: views.py[![][3]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdhuM.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: So do you have some sort of _pagination_? large number of related (FK, M2M) fields that should be fetched? Also include your `view` and `model` files.

Comment: yes. currently i have 1.8k rows. it has foreign key relation with 2 other tables but for now im testing it out with a regular select query(Class.objects.all()). Edited this post with models and views and a sample screenshot of the table

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Okay sorry. I have edited it.

Comment: Try to check locally with `django-debug-toolbar` and see how many queries you have in one page and how much time does it take to load the page locally.